# Persist CSS alterations in Webkit Inspector

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit

Is there a way to get Web Inspector to make my style changes stick past page refreshes?

As I make changes and fixes, before I upload or commit them to the server, it's helpful to see them in the inspector. However, as soon as a link is clicked, the page refreshes and the inspector grabs the server-based version. Is there any way to get around that?